# Dense set of compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

If $X,Y$ be topological spaces with $X$ locally-compact and Hausdorff and $Y$ non-trivial, then $C(X,Y)$ is closed in $Y^X$ when the latter is equipped with the compact-open topology.  So it's clearly not dense.  However, I'm curious, what are some "nicely behaved" dense subsets of $Y^X$ (besides $Y^X-F$ where $F$ is a finite set of functions of $Y^X$).

If possible, some concrete examples when $X,Y$ are Euclidean (of dimension at-least $1$) would be great.

Comment: $Y^X$ in many texts already denotes the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$; the space of *all* functions usually is only considered in the pointwise topology (i.e. as a product space) and the compact-open one is reserved for $C(X,Y)$ and not used on $Y^X$ as it is badly behaved.

Comment: Hi Henno, what do you mean by badly behaved (besides clearly not being separable in familiar settings like when $X,Y$ are Euclidean)?

Comment: Few nice properties like local connectedness, it’s not a topological group or vector space as $C(X,Y)$ is, etc. Is it even regular? Hausdorff yes. But that’s about it. There are few relationships between properties of $X$ or $Y$ and the compact-open $Y^X$.